# How to communicate across two job offers, offering H1-B and GC sponsorship, that I will not continue the process if H1-B fails?

Tags: professionalism, visa

It's very hard to condense my situation down into a short title, so please indulge me with a quick explaination:

H1-B is a yearly visa lottery to allow working with dual-intent in the US. My odds of winning for a single entry are around 30%. It is completely legal to have two "lottery tickets" if they are from two different employers.

I have two job offers, that are both willing to sponsor a H1-B and a GC. To maximize my chances of a successful lottery, I would love for both companies to submit a petition for me. However, this puts me in an ethical, and logistical conundrum.

If Company A wins the H1-B petition, I want to work with them.
Else, if company B wins the H1-B petition, I want to work with Company B. Otherwise, I want to work for Company A and work towards a green card.

This is, bluntly put, not very reasonable to ask. Especially for company B, it would be a  scenario with very slim chances of actually "winning" and introduce a lot of uncertainty in their hiring process which is unacceptable.  I could perhaps accept both and then reneg one after the lottery drawing end of the month, depending on the results, but that feels unethical. So I'm not sure if there even is any reasonable way to ask what I'm looking for, or if I should just stick with Company A and take my chances. Is there even an acceptable and sensible way to ask for this?

Comment: So, I asked whether the process had changed. Apparently, it did. Why do you keep insisting I'm mixing up two programs?

Comment: @Abigail I didn't know (or research, shame on me) that it worked differently before. It has been that way since I started bothering with it a few years ago, and I just assumed it's been that way since a long time. Mea culpa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a tricky situation since the US immigration system is so screwy and unpredictable. I had a person working for me who lost the H1B lottery three years in a row and we had to get really creative to keep them in the country.

Sponsoring H1B and GC is a significant effort and expense, so there is definitely an ethical aspect to your behavior.

I think your best of course of action would be

1. Accept offer of company A (assuming it's your first choice)
2. Be open with company B. Tell them that you have two offers and since there is no way of knowing which (or if any) H1B will get through you would like to try both and that if both are successful you would choose A

Then B can decide what to do. As a hiring manager I would prefer this option over a simple decline. There is a good chances that they will rescind the offer, but it's also possible that they will go for it. The chance of both H1Bs winning is less than 10%, so they still have a good chance of getting you. That's still better than 0% if you just decline the offer.

To me this is 100% ethical. A doesn't need to know, since if their H1B comes through, you will go with them no matter what. Company B can make an informed decision for themselves

Comment: What would I tell A if I reneg on their offer if A loses and B wins?

Comment: That you are not willing to wait another year for the next lottery. It's unreasonable to expect that you put your  career on hold indefinitely betting on the outcome of a 30% lottery. How long would this be binding? One year, two, five, 20 years ? To me, waiting for the first lottery is a reasonable expectation, but anything after this is open to discussion.

Comment: They're willing to work remotely with me even if the lottery fails.

Comment: That is very relevant information. Go with A then and forget B.

Comment: @Joe, If they are willing to do that, make sure that the salary and benefits are written into the contract, even if you're working from abroad.

Answer (score 1):

You have actual job offers from two companies, each of which believes that, should you accept the offer, you will work for them. If they don't happen to win the H1-B, they will do the slower Green Card thing.

But in reality, if A doesn't win the lottery and B does, you won't work for A even though you've accepted their offer. So this plan feels unfair to A. And if neither wins the lottery, you won't go through the green card thing with B even though you've accepted their offer. So it also feels unfair to B.

You haven't specified why getting in on the H1-B is so much better than getting in on the green card that you would be willing to switch companies over it. If there is some super compelling reason (you can start months or a year earlier; you salary isn't limited or capped; you are taxed differently, I don't know) then you could **in theory** share this reason with A and B. However most companies want to hear "my goal is to work with you" not "my goal is to achieve a particular immigration status" so it seems like there's a lot of downside to telling them this, for no gain. They aren't going to do anything different when they learn your acceptance is actually tentative, other than maybe withdraw their offer to hire someone who will be sure to truly accept it.

If you really intend to stick to this plan, just stick to it without telling them. Accept both offers, go through the lottery, and then tell whichever one you are declining that because you didn't get the H1-B, you are not going to come and take the job after all. They will be disappointed, but that is something that happens when you hire someone who has to move to take the job. It isn't going to ruin their year or your reputation. You say it feels unethical. It feels unethical because it **is** unethical. You're trying to maximize your own gain (H1-B chances) and risking their certainty in their hiring process to do so. Of course, that certainty is never 100% anyway, but you are lowering it. If that feels wrong, don't do it. Just accept from A and tell B you took another offer.